# in d3: Can Select "body" but cannot select "div" or "#id" or ".class"

Tags: select, d3.js

Using d3.  Cannot do d3.select("")

I am very new to d3 - just started Scott's book and was trying the simple example in  the first shot at binding data.

My page's body element has exactly one element - a div with id="abc" and class = "abc".

The example below works when the d3.select is of ("body").  I get the expected results appended to the end of the body.

However, when I change the d3.select to ("div") or to ("#abc") or to (".abc"), I do not get the expected 5 paragraphs appended to the div; it is as though the script was never there. All I see are the two headers (h1 and h2).

I am sure the problem and solution are quite simple to the experienced.  However, to this newby, they are baffling.  Specifically, why does d3.select only seem to work with a "body" selector and not with any other legal selector?

Here is the relevant code:

```
<h1>Testing</h1>
<script>
var dataset = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
d3.select("div") //"div" doesn't work - only "body" works
   .selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
   .text(function (d) { return "NewParagraph " + d; });
</script>

<div id="abc" class="abc">
<h2>This is a Div</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I stumbled on the solution.

I placed the script immediately before the  and all the selects I was unable to make work now work

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the script after the elements you work with have been defined. You're defining the `div` after the script. It should work fine if you put the `div` before the `script`.